# Parallel.Invoke for threads in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, invoke

Can anybody tell me how to invoke all threads at once from a list of threads.

actually I have saved all threads in a list after creating them but if I use `th.start()` and `th.join()` methods, every thread starts one by one. I want them to start all at once.

I've used time function to see the starting and ending time for each thread but non of them starts simultaneously.

I am starting thread like this:

```
foreach (Thread st in threadss)
{
    st.Start();
    st.Join();
}
```

but I want to start them like this:

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => st1.Start(), () => st2.Start(), .....);
```

please help

Comment: Why do you call `Thread.Join`? I'm curious because you might as well not use threads at all with this pattern.

Comment: More importantly, why do you need to make your own threadpool? Is there a reason why you don't use the TPL?

Answer (score 3):

Why not `.Start()` them first, then `.Join()` them? Should work fine.

```
foreach (var st in threadss) {
    st.Start();
}
foreach (var st in threadss) {
    st.Join();
}
```